# Persistent bottom sheet with recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-design-library, bottom-sheet

I have a scrollable view with persistent bottom sheet in a coordinator layout.

Is it possible to automatically adjust bottom margin to scrollable view when bottom sheet is shown? Otherwise bottom sheet overlaps some items in scrollable view.

Attribute layout_marginBottom in scrollable view is not always applicable because bottom sheet might be in hidden state.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="Item 1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="#ffbb3d"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="Item 2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="#a4ff3d"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="Item 3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="#3d77ff"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:background="#e6e6e6"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Bottom sheet title"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In this sample layout "Item 3" is always below bottom sheet.

**Update**

I found a solution using custom layout behaviour in NestedScrollView.

Bottom sheet layout should be extended from some "marker class", for example

```
public class BottomSheetFrameLayout extends FrameLayout { 
//... 
}
```

Otherwise you can detect bottom sheet by id for example.

And in custom behaviour we can check if dependency instanceof BottomSheetFrameLayout and in that case append some bottom margins or translation to view:

```
public class BottomSheetScrollingViewBehavior extends AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior {
// ...

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof BottomSheetFrameLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        // Add bottom margins or translation to view
    }
}
```